# ActiveRecord has_many with through use join model order at higher precendence

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models that are related to each other using a has_many with a join model using the through option.

```
Class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :c, through: :b, order: 'b.rank'

Class B < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :a
   belongs_to :c

Class C < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :a, through: :b

   default_scope order(:rank)
```

The tables for both classes B and C each have a rank column.  Rank on C is intended to be a global rank and the rank on the pivot table (B) is intended to be the rank for the association that overrides the global rank if present.

The problem is that ActiveRecord, while adding both tables' rank columns into the ORDER BY clause, is adding them in the opposite order as desired in this case.  For example, the following code:

```
A.find(1).c
```

produces

```
SELECT c.* FROM c INNER JOIN b ON c.id=b.c_id WHERE b.a_id = 1 ORDER BY c.rank, b.rank
```

The default_scope on the C class appears to be taking precedence over the order attribute of the association. I cannot remove the default scope on class C, as other functionality throughout the app would be affected by that.

Is there a way to change this behavior for a given relationship?

Comment: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil

Comment: @fey beat me to it.  I've run into similar problems.  Specifying order in the query rather than by default scope is the best way forward. Default scopes hide too much mechanism far away from its application.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the post and I definitely agree.  However, I did not add the default_scope in this case unfortunately.  I was hoping to not have to comb through the app and update every bit of code that is expecting the behavior of that default_scope however, or at least save that refactoring for a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best practice would be to define the scope and call it explicitly.

Comment: I agree, was hoping for a work around for the interim until I can refactor all the code using the default scope :(